# how to use sql cursor attribute in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

i open a sql cursor with name is lcaaa. inside with that loop cursor, i execute a sql statenent into a variable. and i use sql%found to get result information about that sql statemnent (not sql cursor)

```
OPEN lcaaa FOR SELECT Id, Searchvalue FROM bbb ;

LOOP
FETCH lcaaa INTO lnid, lcsearchvalue ;

EXIT  WHEN (lcaaa%NotFound);


     SELECT dd
     INTO a
     FROM aaa
        WHERE x=y 

    IF sql%found THEN

    END IF

END LOOP
```

when sql%found is false , i get error that procedure. they say no data found and exit loop in sql cursor.

oracle does not support sql cursor attribute (like sql%found) inline cursor loop ?

Comment: You cant use implicit cursor attribute inside explicit cursor.

Comment: i know your meaning. but maybe you are wrong english. i used explicit cursor in implicit cursor. is it true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does support and error is not because of or at the point where you are using `sql%found` but because of the select statement above it. [Dbfiddle with a small test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8134923e9365a7faf3fec349ea8d00c9)

From official website: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sql_cursor.htm)

`If a SELECT INTO statement fails
to return a row, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception
NO_DATA_FOUND, whether you check SQL%NOTFOUND on the next line or not. A SELECT INTO statement that calls a SQL aggregate function never raises NO_DATA_FOUND, because those functions always return a value or a NULL. In such cases, SQL%NOTFOUND returns FALSE.`

Above statement says about `sql%notfound` which is also same for `sql%found`

You always can read more in those official websites for more information and I just highlighted the cause in your case.